# what does process geometry mean?

Tags: arm

from ARM DDI 01001, there is a term: process geometry, does it mean the chip size?

*Caches and write buffers to improve average system performance are now commonplace in ARM® memory 
systems. Core clock rates have increased at a faster rate than memory access times over recent years. This 
factor, and smaller **process geometries**, the economics of on-chip memory, and system power constraints 
have encouraged the use of caches to meet growing system demands.*

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to the size of the "wires" in a processor (or memory) such as "35 micron". The term "process" refers to how the chips (processor) is fabricated and not the *process*-or :-) So, for a *given layout*, a processor with a smaller process geometry will be smaller. However, if the processor is changed (e.g. more cache or processing unit are added) then the processor die size may actually increase. Smaller process geometries usually imply less power consumption as well.

Comment: thanks for your clarification between process geometry and die size.

Comment: I would add that leakage currents across transistors increase with a decrease in process geometry for a given clock speed.  This means the IC will consume more power, in general, even in sleep states.  For that reason, smaller process geometry often also means slower clock.

Comment: As @Eric says, leakage current increases as the process geometry shrinks. OTOH, dynamic leakage **de**creases as the process geometry shrinks. For current CPUs where the feature size is tens of nanometres and the clock speed is a gigahertz or two, the static leakage is tiny compared to the dynamic leakage, so putting the same design on a smaller process usually **de**creases the power use overall, and often lets you increase the clock speed as well. When you have to decrease the clock speed, it's usually because your power-per-unit-area is higher, giving you a heat dissipation problem.